# How to do setState for an object inside constructor -> state?

Tags: reactjs

How to do setState for {items.name} an object which is inside constructor -> this.state -> items: { name: '', age:'' }

Comment: constructor is where you initialize the state. no need to use setState in the constructor

Comment: But why? If you want state initialization in the constructor, means you have value with you at time of component initialization or even before `componentWillMount`. Then why dont you directly initialize it in the constructor instead of using the async method

Comment: I didnt convey properly..sorry for that                                    
 constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bugTitle : '',
            bugDescription : '',
            bugType : '',
            bugDetail : {
                title : '',
                description : '',
                type: ''
            },
            bugDetailArray : []
        }
    }   Here i want to setState for the "title" which is inside the object

Answer (score 0):

Inside the constructor instead on doing `setState` you can assign value to `this.state`

```
this.state = {
   name: "",
   age: ""
}
```

But there is rarely a use case where in you need to do it this way.

Comment: constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            bugTitle : '',
            bugDescription : '',
            bugType : '',
            bugDetail : {
                title : '',
                description : '',
                type: ''
            },
            bugDetailArray : []
        }
    }

Comment: Here i need to setState for Title which is inside an object

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set the state of bugDetail ,

in constructor you can do this:

`constructor(props) {
 super(props); 
this.state = { bugTitle : '', 
bugDescription : '', 
bugType : '',
 bugDetail : { title : '', description : '', type: '' }, 
bugDetailArray : [] } }`

do  the following later: ->

```
 this.setState({bugDetail:{title:"updated",description : 'olderdesc', type:"older"}})
```

also can do:->

```
updateTitle(updatedTitle){
let newBugdetail = this.state.bugDetail;
newBugdetail.title = updatedTitle;
this.setState({bugDetail:newBugdetail })
}
```

else you need to keep the title as an outside key in the state

Comment: The updated value is not showing..its showing empty after setState also

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h0taey7z/                          I am a new bie to react if my code is not proper then please tell how to improve my code quality

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/crystalthinker/hp92g13x/ check this did the same as my answer, will check your fiddle as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your constructor looks like this

```
constructor(props) { 
  super(props); 
  this.state = { 
    bugTitle : '', 
    bugDescription : '', 
    bugType : '', 
    bugDetail : { 
        title : '', 
        description : '', 
        type: '' 
    }, 
    bugDetailArray : [] 
  } 
}
```

So in order to change the state using `setState` in your function

```
someFunction = (e) => {
  let inputName = e.target.name;
     let inputValue = e.target.value;
     let updatedFormState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
     updatedFormState.bugDetail["title"] = inputValue;
     this.setState(updatedFormState);
}
```